# How can I save my season dresses properly without any wardrobe and box?

Tags: clothing, personal-care, comfort, storage

I live in a little room don't have enough space for any wardrobe and box for saving clothes. I face difficulty when season off and I did not save my season dresses properly. So I waste a huge collection of dresses because of carelessness.
How can I save my dresses properly without any wardrobe box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

10 Smart Clothes Storage Ideas:

1. Repurpose an old trunk.

“A great way to store items is to use a wood trunk,” home blogger Jackie Hausler says. “Not only are trunks stylish, but they also hide items that would normally be out and about, making a room cluttered. “

With a little love, you can transform any trunk to match your room’s decor.

“I took an old trunk I found at an antique store and brought it back to life with some wood stain and upholstery fabric,” she explains. “Now, it is as good as new and can be used for a variety of storage options. I think it is the perfect hideaway for accessories like hats and purses! Put it at the foot of your bed, or in your living room; trunks look wonderful in any room you choose!”

2. Add a shelved rack.

“If you have a spot outside your door to the garage (most of us do), where you can set up a simple shelf, this is a great spot for shoes to rest before kids cross the threshold,” Samantha, a professional organizer, National Association of Professional Organizers member and home blogger says. “This means shoes will always be exactly where you look – the first time. No more searching around the house. No more not finding a match.”

You can also use the rack as a home for your socks. Assign each member of your family a bin and fill it with their socks, keeping those easy-to-misplace pairs together and ready to go whenever anyone heads out the door.

3. Try a detached wardrobe rack.

If you simply want to mimic a traditional closet, opt for a clothes rack (you can find one at IKEA for as little as $9.99.) If your clothing rack is small, be strategic about how you fill it to get the most out of your space.

“A MUST is to use all of the same hangers, professional organizer Jennifer Ford Berry says, “and they MUST be slimline if you are short on space.”

You can also double your hanging space by using pop can tabs. Slide your first hanger’s hook through the top of the tab, and hand a second hanger from the bottom of the tab.

4. Use the space under your bed:

The space under your bed may have been a little scary when you were a kid, but there’s no reason to be afraid: we’ve checked, and there are no monsters. In fact, the space beneath your bed is a great place to organize and protect your shoes and handbags.

It’s also a good spot to store heavy sweaters, since you’ll avoid those unwanted stretched-out shoulder marks caused by hangers.

Use rolling storage drawers, short plastic bins, and other under-the-bed storage containers that fit nicely in this small space. If your bed is too low to the ground to fit storage underneath it, opt for simple bed risers (they’re not just for dorm rooms!) or shipping pallets. You can find many stylish options online, or choose to keep your storage drawers hidden with a longer bed skirt.

5. Hang your accessories:

If you’re like most of us (I know I am guilty), you probably forget about your jewelry, scarves and other accessories because they’re not stored in plain sight. Instead of tucking these items away, embrace your flair by making it part of your room’s decor.

Use Command hooks, wall organizers or even just thin nails to display jewelry. When it comes to trickier items, like tights and scarves, Julie Ann from Julie Ann Art recommends using a clothes hanger: simply tie each item in a knot around the hanger and put it on display. The hanger also fits nicely on a detached clothes rack!

6. Install a picture ledge.

Picture ledges are great way to open up storage opportunities when you don’t have a lot of floor space. Install one on an open wall, and attach a rail to its underside. This will let you hang hooks for clothes, bags and jackets. You can also choose to screw in cup hooks to the bottom, allowing you to hang lighter items, like tank tops or necklaces. Use the top of the ledge to hold sunglasses, handbags or shoes.

7. Rethink your bookcase.

Instead of filling your bookcases with, well, books, rethink the way you see those shelves. Use the space to store t-shirts, pants, sweaters and other items that work well folded, like Samantha did. It’s also a good way to place to keep your jewelry, shoes and accessories. Plus, you won’t have to worry about rummaging around drawers to find your favorite sweatshirt or go-to party necklace, since it will all be easily visible.

If you don’t like keeping all of your items exposed, install a rod and hang decorative curtains to cover them up.

8. Think upwards:

Another way to fake a closet is by hanging a clothes rod from the ceiling. Install strong hooks to your ceiling, and attach rope to dangle below both of them. Tightly tie your rope along a rod as long as the distance between the two hooks will allow, giving you a place to hang your wrinkle-prone items that can’t be folded away. If you space is tall enough (and your rope is strong enough), you can add another rod below your first one for double the hanging space.

9. Take advantage of other rooms:

Who says your clothes have to stay in your bedroom? If your living room, dining room, home office or hallways have extra space you aren’t necessarily using, take full advantage by utilizing these areas for clothes storage. Keep your items concealed by using dressers that can double as tv stands, side tables or buffets.

10. Rotate clothes are out of season:

If you’re short on space, the best way to get the most out of your home is by cycling out clothes that are out of season. Chances are you aren’t going to need your winter coat and wool sweaters in the summer, or your sundresses and flip flops in the winter. So why let them take up precious space? Keep these items safe by placing them in sealed plastic bins, trunks or suitcases in a safe and dry part of your home.

Reference:https://www.lifestorage.com/blog/organization/10-innovative-clothes-storage-ideas-when-you-have-no-closet/

Answer (score 2):

[Vacuum storage bags](https://www.spedalon.com/) - hugely space efficient and protect your clothes at the same time.

Comment: I got a couple of these last spring to put my winter clothes inside during the summer and they are amazing. Winter clothes usually use a lot of space, but this way they get compressed. You can buy them in Ikea for expample